# How to make arrayed objects have independent rotation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, constraints, parent

How should I go about making an array (***Modifier***) of objects have independent rotation? The base has a "Locked Track" ***constraint*** to an empty, but if I move the empty (to move rotate the base) it only changes the direction of the array. This is the setup: [image]

Comment: You will have to construct the array differently. You can do this with Sverchok or Animation nodes.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, what about create your object, then add your Constraint, then link duplicate your object with alt D, and shift R to repeat your duplication